# Deriving the 2s to 1s transition rate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, orbitals, fermis-golden-rule

The hydrogen $2s$ to $1s$ is forbidden so it has a long mean-life (0.125 s vs 1.6 ns). Fermis golden rule can be used to derive the $2p\to1s$, but it predicts a zero rate (I think) when applied to the $2s\to1s$.

Is there a fairly straightforward way (even if it is numerical) to derive the $2s\to1s$ transition rate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way of estimating the 2s-1s transition. Fermi's golden rule comes from applying first order perturbations theory where the purturbation is the electromagnetic field.  The 2s-1s transition probability is 0 in first order so you have to employ 2nd order purturbation theory (again the purturbation is the electromagnetic field).  This is commonly called a two-photon process and will be suppressed by the factor 1/137 compared to a first order term. That is why it is called a forbidden transition.   I'll leave it to you to Google the appropriate terms and find the actual calculation.

Comment: Is "estimate" accurate within a relative error of 1/137 or so? Or is it an order-of-magnitude?

Comment: The third order and higher terms should be down by at least another factor of 1/137 so my should be accurate to about 1%